# fields comparison in org-tables

Tags: org-mode

I want to check wheather a column and a row is the same like this:

```
    |   | A | B | C |
    -----------------
    | A | X | 0 | 0 |
    | B | 0 | X | 0 |
    | C | 0 | 0 | X |
```

If I use the following formula:

```
    #TBLFM: @<<$<<..@>$> = if ($1==@1,X,0)
```

then I get the following:

```
    |   | A | B | C |
    -----------------
    | A | X | A = B ? X : 0 | A = C ? X : 0 |
    | B | B = A ? X : 0 | X | B = C ? X : 0 |
    | C | C = A ? X : 0 | C = B ? X : 0 | X |
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is comparing symbols, so `A==A` is always true. But the result for `A==B` is the whole symbolic expression.

Adding quotes to your row/column headers treats them as strings:

```
|   | A | B | C |
|---+---+---+---|
| A | X | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | X | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | X |
#+TBLFM: @<<$<<..@>$> = if ("$1"=="@1",X,0)
```